# Need help with the format exception::Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

property in my mainClass

```
  public Int64 DetailID
        {
            get { return bintDetailID; }
            set { bintDetailID = value; }
        }
```

myClass

```
mainClass obj=new mainClass();
obj.DetailID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

aspx page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DetailID") %>'
CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Visible="false" runat="server" OnCommand="btnEdit_Click"/>
```

Isn't this how u convert string to int ?

```
int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Whats wrong ? plz help..thnx

Comment: what is e.commandargument when you get it.

Comment: when I debug..its showing it as an empty string ""

Comment: When I give hard coded value like obj.DetailID=567; its running alright

Comment: You cannot convert an empty string to int.

Comment: Why is it returning an empty string?I dont get it..Is the following correct ?? CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DetailID") %>'

Comment: ohh..erm no its not inside of a repeater or anything :| lemme try that...thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Button object is NOT within a databound control like a grid / repeater,
AND If you are trying to Bind the button using the DetailID property, check the following:-

1. Assuming your button is in `testPage.aspx`, the codebehind class for `testPage.aspx` i.e `class testPage` should have a property of type `Int64` called DetailID.
   eg : `Int64 DetailID get; set;`
2. Assuming mainClass is some custom class of yours, somewhere in Page_Load, you will have to do a `this.DetailID = mainClassObject.DetailID;` where `this` = instance of your page.
3. In your `page_load` method, additionally, you will have to do a `Page.DataBind()`. This is because a non-databound control like button does not have its own DataBind() method.

Note 1: If your testPage.DetailID = Int32 / int, you will need to do the conversion in the setter method or before that as y0ur mainClass is an Int64

Note 2: From your comments, you seem to be saying that Int64 doesnt exist. Which is weird!
Try using the fully qualified name i.e System.Int64 and see if that works!

Comment: I tried that already..it said Int64 doesn't exist in the current context (!!??)

Comment: @Happy Soul - if your button is NOT WITHIN a databound control, like a Grid, then you can check my updated answer and see if it works!!

Comment: ok I have implemented like u said..now the master Page of my aspx page is throwing "Object reference null exception" when I include the line "Page.DataBind();" in my code.. when I comment out this line in my PageLoad method this exception is not thrown BUT again the e.commandArguments becomes  empty string like "" how do I use thsi non data bound control ? plz help..thnx

Comment: @Happy Soul - What `Page.DataBind()` does is that it binds all datasources on your page to their respective controls. What is the code of the line where you are getting your object reference error from? Can u ascertain if all other datasources on your page are populated with values BEFORE u do the Page.DataBind(). If any of your datasources are not populated, you are likely to get an object reference error. To test if this part works ok, i suggest you first comment out all other datasources / databound controls on your page...

Answer (score 4):

Int.parse is used to covert into 32 bit integer value.According to your question

```
 public Int64 DetailID
        {
            get { return bintDetailID; }
            set { bintDetailID = value; }
        }
```

Its 64 bit.

```
try Int64.parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

if you are getting empty value check

```
 (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
Int64.parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Hope it works.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried that already..it says int64 doesnt exist in the current context..why is that ??

Comment: argh..why did C# had to be case sensitive!? sry :/ was typing "int64" instead of "Int64" ..ok now the exception still is being thrown..still the string is empty only :( why wont it fetch the value :((

Comment: @Prateek..its empty string..the button's not inside of a data bound control..trying that now..new to all this so thot Eval method might work with controls not inside of data bound controls too..thnx for trying to help

Comment: May be a case:-check value of <%#Eval("DetailID") %>

Comment: @Happy Soul:-Your welcome hope you will solve the issue very soon.Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, try setting the value for `CommandArgument` from the code-behind ...

```
btnEdit.CommandArgument = DetailID.ToString();
```

---

One doubt I have though, is if in your .aspx file you should write

```
CommandArgument='<%=Eval("DetailID") %>'
```

instead of

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("DetailID") %>'
```

(note the `=` vs `#`)